# Outputting a member of a vector of classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two classes

```
class MyStoreClass
{
public:
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> my_vec;
};
```

and

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    double member1;
    int member2;
};
```

I have a vector of around 10000 MyClasses 
I would like to be able to use a function such as

```
template<typename T>
void MyStoreClass::output_member(T MyClass::* chosen_member)
{
    std::cout << chosen_member << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Edit: I'd like to output `member` from each MyClass in the vector

Comment: Something like `chosen_member->MemberVariable?`

Comment: Maybe read up on pointers to members?

Comment: I'm guessing by `chosen_member` you're trying to select between `member1` and `member2`?

Comment: Yes, I have many members in `MyClass` and I'd like to select the member by passing it to `output_member`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to describe what the function should *do*, so I'm assuming that you want the function to print the corresponding member of all elements of `my_vec`.

You need to explicitly dereference the `unique_ptr` in order to use the pointer-to-member dereferencing operator.
The rest is straightforward:

```
template<typename T>
void MyStoreClass::output_member(T MyClass::* chosen_member)
{
    for (const auto& ptr: my_vec)
    {
        if (ptr)
            std::cout << (*ptr).*chosen_member << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "[null]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

Continuing with the assumptions, I'm going to assume that by "standard" you mean "the pre-C++11 loop that I'm used to", since the range-based loop has been standard for quite a few years now.

```
template<typename T>
void MyStoreClass::output_member(T MyClass::* chosen_member)
{
    for (std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>::const_iterator i = my_vec.begin();
         i != my_vec.end();
         ++i)
    {
        if (*i)
            std::cout << (*i)->*chosen_member << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "[null]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The test for null would be of `*ptr` (which gives a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>  &`) not `ptr` (which tests the iterator itself).  And the output would be of `(*ptr)->*chosen_member`.

Comment: @Peter No, `ptr` isn't an iterator. It's a`const std::unique_ptr<MyClass> &`.

Comment: How would I go about outputting the chosen members with a standard for loop?